# UIAlert Controller is not displaying

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I click at top left corner like the following image ,it is not selecting , I had set a 64 distance from the top view which is between navigation controller and table view , I think it is not selecting because navigation controller had covered half of the first cell

[image: [![]

[image]

Comment: So you want to ask about navigation controller or alert controller?

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: In second image when i am selecting at top corner of cell , its not selecting

Comment: is there anything related to UIAlertController? Is that button on top corner there?

Comment: Hey after you resize the tableView.. please remember to update its constraint until the orange dotted line gone.

Comment: its not related to UIAlertcontroller , when touch the top corner we have to go other controller, at top controller touch is not recogniting

Comment: @Ravi have you created an action outlet for the top corner button? Or are you directly trying to segue it to a view on click?